# AWS SDK- NodeJS - Invalid parameter: PlatformApplicationArn Reason: Wrong number of slashes in relative portion of the ARN

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I get the following error:

"Invalid parameter: PlatformApplicationArn Reason: Wrong number of slashes in relative portion of the ARN.',
code: 'InvalidParameter"    My code is below:

```
      var apiKey = request.params.apiKey;
    var deviceToken = request.params.deviceToken;
    var arn = 'arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:898980891534:loan_approved_android'
  //  var arn = request.params.arn

    var params = {
      PlatformApplicationArn: arn, /* required */
      Token: deviceToken, /* required */
      Attributes: {
        someKey: 'STRING_VALUE',
        /* anotherKey: ... */
      },
      CustomUserData: 'STRING_VALUE'
    };
    sns.createPlatformEndpoint(params, function(err, data) {

         if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred

      else     console.log(data);           // successful response

    });
```

Comment: For your arn value, where do you get the number, 898980891534, from? Is that your gcm project id?

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is a problem with the resource/resource type in the ARN.

See [Amazon Resource Names (ARNs) and AWS Service Namespaces](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html)

Note that if this is an SNS endpoint ARN, the final ARN is generated by the SNS service after the device token is registered with SNS.

You will only know the final ARN until the device is registered using the device token.